# How can I use cross-compile (arm64) in x86 centos7 linux

Tags: docker, qemu, virtualization

I am using x86 centos7 linux.
I want to use cross-compile to arm64 in docker
but I can't use `docker buildx --platform` because of the low Kenel version (centos7)

What should I do?

I've searched about QEMU, docker to solve this problem but I can't find the solution.

---

I want to make the system like this

```
| app1 | app2 | app3 | app4 |  
|          docker           |  
|     qemu(arm64, x86..)    |  
|    host os (computer os)  |  
|    host h/w (computer)    |
```

or.... maybe like this (uncertain)

```
| app1 | app2 | app3 | app4 |  
|     qemu(arm64, x86..)    |  
|          docker           |  
|    host os (computer os)  |  
|    host h/w (computer)    |
```

*app1:arm64 / app2:x86 / app3:arm64 / app4:x86

Please remember that centos7 uses yum, not apt.

Comment: centos7 is EOL since 3 years. the easy answer here is "upgrade"

Comment: @RickRackow there might be plenty of reasons to keep using a software version. I understand your comment but let's wait for someone to have an answer to this.

Comment: https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static is a way to run non-native docker images directly (i.e. docker can just start images with `--platform linux/arm64`). I don't know if it depends on the same kernel features that break buildx, though.

Comment: You're right @S.Dre let me get a real answer here. Mainly the ability to use `buildx` depends on your version of docker-engine, not your kernel per se. In later versions (that might not be available for you) buildx is available as plugin for docker so you can run commands like `docker buildx`, however if you have at least docker engine 19.03 or above, you can run the buildx binary directly and still get builds as stated here https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/160#issuecomment-541161728

Comment: yes, buildx depends on my version of docker-engine(19.03). 

but, Kernel version should be newer than 4.8.  
Centos 7 with kernel 3.10 doesn't support cross compilation on docker images.  

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778867/docker-cross-compilation-missing-platforms-in-buildx